# How to call original synchronous method that has async overload in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, xcode13, swift-concurrency

Recently switched to Xcode 13.

I have an AVAsset writer, and trying to call the method

```
writer.finishWriting()
```

which now has an async version, as well as the synchronous version.

I want to call the original synchronous version, but am getting the error:

```
"'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency. 
Add 'async' to function to make it asynchronous"
```

How can I call the original synchronous/pre-Xcode 13 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to add the trailing closure that the original function is expecting.

You want to use [`finishWriting(completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriter/1390432-finishwriting). The definition takes a trailing closure, `completionHandler`:

```
func finishWriting(completionHandler handler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

If you add the trailing closure:

```
writer.finishWriting {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

the code will compile as expected.